# Laravel Storage files get damaged while uploading

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, storage

So I've been using ftp functions `(manually setting $conn_id, making fpt_put($conn_id,...), conn_close etc)` in my project,

now I've added "use Storage" in **my controller**, **set host**, **username** and **password** for ftp in filesystems.php and changed all the functions in my controller to **"Storage::"** type.

The problem is that my files get damaged while uploading on the storage. After upload files successfully appear (I've tried uploading on both local and remote ftp storage), but I can't open them, getting the **"Could not load image"** error on files put in my **/storage/app** folder and empty square when opening an url from the remote storage. While I was using **ftp_put(...) and stuff,** everything was working perfectly.

The only thing I've noticed is the error explanation given when trying to open a file placed in /storage/app:

> Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x2f
>   0x76)

What could this one mean and how could I handle this situation? Would highly appreciate any possible help!

UPD: looks like the file somewhere during the upload stops being a file of its native format, and then gets renamed back forcibly, which causes corruption. Like, I upload .jpeg file, something happens, then it gets saved with .jpeg at the end, not being a .jpeg anymore. Still no idea.

Comment: Possibly, the thing is that while using **ftp_put()** I also specified the mode - **FTP_BINARY**, and then I removed this specification, because nothing was told about it in Laravel docs. Like, if **ftp_put()** looks like **ftp_put($conn_id, where_from, where_to, FTP_BINARY)**, in **Storage::** it's like **(where_from, where_to, visibility)**, and nothing is said about mode. So, I have no clue what to do with this knowledge.

Comment: are you ok that I give you the way to do it right? or do you insist on doing it the XIX century style?

Comment: @Arminius I have already solved this problem, but I would appreciate if you tell me about the "right" way anyways

Answer (score 1):

Well I got it, the problem was that I left all the paths in () like they were with ftp_put(), like (to, from), but **Storage:: requires contents, not path, in "from" place**, so **Storage::put(to, file_get_contents(from)**, 'public') solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is for information purposes, since she has requested another way of doing it. No need to thumb it up or down.

```
    public function store(Request $request){            
     $this->validate($request, array(
// I have done the validations but skip to show it here
          // OBTAINING THE IMAGES 
                    $files = $request->images;               
                    // COUNTING HOW MANY WERE RECEIVED
                    $file_count = count($files);                
                    // INITIALIZING A COUNTER
                    $uploadcount = 0;       

                foreach($files as $file) {

                    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

                    $temporary = public_path(). '/uploads/temporary/' . $property->id;
                    if(!file_exists($temporary)) File::makeDirectory($temporary);
                    $temp = $file->move($temporary, $filename);  // This is where they temporary stay to be fetched for processing 


                    $thumbs = public_path(). '/uploads/thumbs/' . $property->id;
                    if(!file_exists($thumbs)) File::makeDirectory($thumbs);
                    Image::make($temp)->resize(240,160)->save($thumbs . '/' . $filename);


                    // We are setting up another directory where we want to save copies with other sizes
                    $gallery= public_path(). '/uploads/gallery/' . $property->id;
                    if(!file_exists($gallery)) File::makeDirectory($gallery);
                    Image::make($temp)->resize(400,300)->save($gallery . '/' . $filename);

                    $picture = new Picture;
                    $picture->property_id = $property->id;
                    $picture->name = $filename;
                    $picture->save();
                    $uploadcount ++;

                }


                if($uploadcount == $file_count){
                      Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully'); 
                      return Redirect()->route('property.show', $property->id);
                    } 
                else{ Session::flash('errors',  'screwed up'); 
                     return Redirect::to('upload')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
                    }

        }
```